# An unwanted level and wrong calculation on the graphic on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                   'city':['Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Lyon','Dax','Dax','Lyon','Lyon','Lyon'],
                   'type':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','B','A','B','B'],
                   'val':[100,90,95,95,90,75,100,70,75,90,95,85]})
    id  city    type    val
0   1   Pau     A       100
1   2   Pau     A       90
2   3   Pau     A       95
3   4   Pau     A       95
4   5   Pau     B       90
5   6   Pau     B       75
6   7   Lyon    B       100
7   8   Dax     A       70
8   9   Dax     B       75
9   10  Lyon    A       90
10  11  Lyon    B       95
11  12  Lyon    B       85
```

And I want to create a plot grouped by variable `city`, and get the frequency percentage per type. I have tried this:

```
df.groupby(['city','type']).agg({'type':'count'}).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum()).unstack().plot()
```

[image]

But I get wrong values per group and an unwanted 'None'. The expected values should be:

```
type    A   B
city        
Dax     .50 .50
Lyon    .33 .66
Pau     .66 .33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your requirement, you may want crosstab with normalize:

```
pd.crosstab(df['city'],df['type'],normalize='index').plot()
```

---

[image]

Where:

```
print(pd.crosstab(df['city'],df['type'],normalize='index'))

type         A         B
city                    
Dax   0.500000  0.500000
Lyon  0.250000  0.750000
Pau   0.666667  0.333333
```

Comment: Hello @anky, thank you for the solution and time on this question, didn't know about crosstab, perhaps my approach with lambda was unnecessary given that simpler but powerful code you provide. Have a great day!